# In what order do the commands in the Image run?

Tags: image, qml

I want the command lines in the Image contained in the QML file to run in the order in the example. But it runs first the third line, then the first and second line.
There is a sequence order that I don't understand.
When the Image I want is visible, the first line, second line and 3rd line should run sequentially.

```
Image {
        id: uploadImg
        width: 50
        height: 50
        visible: false
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.bottomMargin: 50
        source: "qrc:/qt/qml/mobile-app/src/assets/images/upload.png"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {

                upload_lbl.text = "Image Uploading"

                // First Line
                delay(2500, function() {
                    previewImg.grabToImage(function(result) {
                      preVolvos.source = result.url;
                    },
                    Qt.size(previewImg.sourceSize.width, previewImg.sourceSize.height));
                })

                // Second Line
                delay(2500, function() {
                    var loadedImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
                    canvas.loadImage(loadedImage)
                })

                //Third Line
                delay(2500, function() {
                if(updatevApp.updateImage(imageID, imgBase64)) {
                    delay(2500, function() {
                        imageModel.clear()
                        stackView.push("qrc:/qt/qml/mobile-app/src/qml/PreviewPage.qml", {logins: logins, sevkNO: sevkNO})
                    })
                } else {
                    upload_lbl.text = "Failed"
                }
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use [`SequentialAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-sequentialanimation.html), [`PauseAnimation`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-pauseanimation.html) and [`ScriptAction `](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-scriptaction.html). or use JS [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).